# Write rule in Cancan or model validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, cancan

**Update:** *After reading the answers, I think I should rephrase my question (as question 3)*

From time to time I get confused as to where I should write a some conditional check: in Cancan ability or in `ActiveRecord` model validation?

As the first example: Say I have a folder model which can be nested. I want prevent deletion of a folder if it is the only child of the parent folder.

This should probably be model logic (as a before_destroy callback). However I would also want to hide the delete button(and block controller action), which seems like the realm of Cancan.

As the second example: I want to prevent deletion of a folder not owned by me.

This will need the use of `current_user` which is stored in the session. I have the impression that session related condition should not touch the model itself, so this is for Cancan. Is it correct?

---

**Question 3:**

If deleting a folder requires both:

1. current_user is owner check (written as Cancan ability)
2. folder is not the only child check (written in model as `destroyable?()`)

Should the Cancan ability also call `model.destroyable?()`, or should I call `model.destroyable?()` separately (in view and in controller)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO Cancan is about *authorization*: is the user allowed to delete a given resource based on who they are. Restricting resource deletion based on *other* criteria falls outside that purview.

This sounds like a combination of authorization and business logic. A view helper might check both if the user `can?` delete the resource, and that the resource is `deletable?`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, I'd do both: put a before_destroy callback that guards against destroying the last record, and also show the button based on CanCan ability. Just hiding the button would not prevent a POST request being sent to your server and deleting the record.

For the second scenario, put the CanCan check on the controller action, so that the destroy action cannot be called without authorization. It does not belong in the model.

Comment: +1 for explicitly mentioning that server-side auth checks are still required, although cancan (ahem) can make this essentially invisible. It's all the same (re-ahem) auth logic.

Comment: So for my edited new 3rd question, would you call model.destroyable?() in cancan ability?